# Using generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface, legacy, type-erasure

Is there any differences between those two class declarations

1:

```
class MyClass <T extends Number & Comparable>
```

2:

```
class MyClass <T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
```

I think that there are differences. But I cannot find an example which would show differences because I don't understand it exact.

Can you show me this example?

Comment: Your first snippet uses a raw type, which you shouldn't use.

Comment: @Paul Bellorano, I read this topic. I have concrete question!

Comment: I suggest you re-read it then. It addresses the question exactly.

Comment: I don't accept with you

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I agree with Paul Bellora. Your question finally boils down to the question linked by him.

Comment: any question finally boils to JLS. and what does it mean?

Comment: I beginner developer and I don't understan this thing

Comment: You should go through the tutorial on [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html), get more familiar with the basics and the terms. And then you will probably agree with him too.

Comment: I have heard that SO better than official documentation

Comment: I think this question will helpful for other developers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference. The first one is using raw types, and thus, is less type-safe. For example:

This works, but should not work

```
class MyClass<T extends Number & Comparable>
{
    void use(T t)
    {
        String s = null;
        t.compareTo(s); // Works, but will cause a runtime error
    }
}
```

Whereas this does not work (because it *should* not work)

```
class MyClass<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
{
    void use(T t)
    {
        String s = null;
        t.compareTo(s); // Compile-time error
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Full code, as requested:

```
class MyClass<T extends Number & Comparable>
{
    void use(T t)
    {
        String s = "Laziness";
        t.compareTo(s); // Works, but will cause a runtime error
    }
}


public class MyClassTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass<Integer> m = new MyClass<Integer>();
        Integer integer = new Integer(42);
        m.use(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: **This works, but should not work** excellent phrase

Comment: **// Works, but will cause a runtime error** can you show full code?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Create an instance of first `MyClass`, and invoke its `use()` method, passing an appropriate argument. This much you can do I think.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Added an example